# High Fan Noise in my OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dc1093tx

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, noise

## Background

I bought my HP Omen (hp dc1093tx) about 2.5 years. In the last 1 year, there has been enormous fan noise higher than the expected one. At first I assumed this to be a hardware issue and took to multiple service centres but none could fix it out.
I was earlier using Windows 10 and then upgraded to Windows 11 assuming if something would change, but none. Recently, I installed Linux as dual boot and things works seamlessly well. My Laptop is silent as expected but when I switch to Windows, the fan sound starts again.

## Things that I have tried so far

1. Updated all the drivers via hp.com
2. firmware is updated to latest one.
3. Uninstalled and removed all the unwanted software's
4. Checked the process and the Disk, Ram, and CPU is all as expected.

Can someone please help out ways to fix this up? I'm not well versed with Systems and Hardware and would be thankful for the support from this forum.

Comment: Can you check with HWInfo and see if anything gets hot actually?

Comment: Linux works, Windows does not. ....  Update any power drivers and probably BIOS.   Reset the Windows Power Plan to default.  Restart and use the default Balanced plan. That should fix Windows.

Comment: Have you cleaned the dust out of the laptop vents?

Answer (score 0):

Some models of OMEN have [Performance Control](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_3912817-3737596-16) options.

- Open the *Performance Control* dashboard.
- Select *Comfort mode*, which "lowers CPU and GPU temperatures, making it suitable for casual tasks. This mode keeps the computer cooler when convenient."

*N.B.*: "Comfort mode is only available on certain computer models. Comfort mode is only available by updating to the latest version of OMEN Gaming Hub (version 6.2.3.0 or later) and updating the BIOS to version F.06 (or later)." Could be that Windows 11 disabled that feature -- *newer* is not always *better*.